# How To Remove Warning: Errors On Website

Tags: php

On my site, I have a script which makes a flash image, the only problem is, every time one is made it has to be configured, I have a cron job that does this every minute. The only problem is before that minute, theres about 500 lines of (Warning: Random Error Code). Is it possible to remove the error codes so the people using the script don't see it?

Comment: What does this have to do with cPanel exactly?

Comment: Yes, probably. Elaborate on the messages and your code. Otherwise impossible to receive help.

Comment: It has to do with cPanel, as Im using cPanel, and there might be a certain fix, using cPanel only.

Comment: I'm using a mouse, but I don't add `mouse` as a tag when I got a PHP question. Please explain more precisely how and where you get the error and how that relates to cPanel.

Comment: Well if there is something in cPanel that I need to set up for it, I think that would make cPanel an important part in it.

Comment: No, that's assuming a certain answer. Your tags should specify what your *question* is about. If you don't get an error in cPanel but in one of your own scripts, then your question is not about cPanel and the tag doesn't belong there. That's why we ask for either the deletion of the tag, or an explanation of how cPanel is the problem.

Comment: And did you notice I removed the tag three minutes before you posted? :0

Answer (score 2):

Turn off error reporting?

```
error_reporting(0);
```

That said, I would try to figure out a better way than just surpressing the errors.

Comment: Do I post this in the script page itself, or .htaccess? This is my first time using cron jobs and .htaccess, so Im not very good at either, yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP script, use

```
 error_reporting(0);
 display_errors(0);
```

Or in your .htaccess file for the entire site(or folder)

```
 php_value display_errors 0
```

But why dont you trigger the configuration script from the script that makes the flash? Then you wont have any errors to deal with...

Just

```
<?php require('configurationscript.php'); ?>
```

In the end of the flash script...

Comment: Do I post this in the script page itself, or .htaccess? This is my first time using cron jobs and .htaccess, so Im not very good at either, yet.

Comment: Cron jobs don't care for .htaccess. Also, this looks like PHP syntax. Woops, [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) say so too. PS, I don't make this stuff up, I Googled it.

Comment: You can set it in the PHP script that produces the errors, or in htaccess for your entire site (good for production environments). But note htaccess has a little other syntax.

Comment: When I add that to .htaccess I get "Internal Server Error".

Comment: Your hosting provider might not let you alter php ini settings. What about the php settings?

Comment: Where do I add the first part? To the script itself or .htaccess? If I add it for the script I have to add the <?php part right?

Comment: Yes <?php before and ?> after ...

Comment: Yes, I did that before, but it just gives me a blank screen. The error messages are, if it helps are... "Warning expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ... on line ..." and "Warning: failed to open stream: Permission denied in ... on line ...".

Comment: I can't set it up to do it automatically because it would require a running script, which isn't allowed, as I used shared hosting. When/if I switch to a server, I won't have to worry about any of this, but for now, I do have to worry about this.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. Try 0 instead of NULL as a value...

Comment: But you dont need a running script to trigger one PHP from another PHP-script. That would also make the cron run every minute unneccesary?

Comment: The script makes a folder every time someone uses it, the folder MUST be 0777 permissions. The cron job checks every folder to see if its 0777, and if its not, changes them to 0777. Ive tried and tried but can't find a way to make this automatic on shared hosting.

Comment: Why cant the same script first create the folder and then in the next line chmod it to 0777?